# Java: unexpected InputStream behavior

Tags: java, url, jar, inputstream

I uploaded a JAR file that was 21 KB in size on my computer to a website. I found the direct link to that JAR file and I create an InputStream to that file:

```
URL url = new URL("addresstofile");
InputStream stream = url.openStream();
```

It would be expected that the amount of bytes available in the stream would be ~21,000. However, the amount available is 7,048. In an attempt to debug, I saved those 7,048 bytes in a byte array and then I write those bytes to a temporary file with the extension ".jar"

I extract the classes in the JAR file (that is 7 KB; the original is 21 KB). Most of the classes are there except I noticed that nested classes are not present. I am not sure as to why that is - is it just a coincidence that the InputStream just cuts out there, or are there some special exceptions to nested classes?

Why is InputStream acting so oddly?
Thanks!

@Neil: This works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The stream only ends when a call to `read()` returns -1. Ignore the `available()` method. It's really not useful for much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the modified version of the code you present, the problem is the comparison. Don't cast 'b' to an int *before* making the comparison with -1. If you do that then if a byte in the stream happens to be 255, you won't be able to differentiate between this byte and the end of the stream.

So make the comparison with -1 on the int returned from read(). Then if it's *not* -1, cast the value to a byte and put it in the array (or whatever).

```
int b;
while ((b = stream.read()) != -1)
{
    data[length++] = (byte) b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `available()` on an input stream tells you how many bytes can be read right now - for network I/O isn't necessarily the whole file, most likely what is just buffered in local socket. Loop and keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

> It would be expected that the amount of bytes available in the stream
>   would be ~21,000

Why?

How can you possibly know that the number of bytes available to be read without blocking was 21,000?

Comment: Because the file was 21 KB on my computer.

Comment: @MartinTuskevicius So? How do you know the I/O system can read all that without blocking? My question was intended to get you thinking about the *actual* definition of the available() method, and to realize that it isn't specified to return the total length of the stream. Indeed there is a specific warning about that in the Javadoc.